# I want to get All hidden Bookmarks from word document using office JS

Tags: javascript, office-js, add-in, word-addins

I want to Get All hidden bookmarks names from my document in word using word JS add-in
using this is I am trying but not done.

[getBookmarks(includeHidden, includeAdjacent)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/word/word.range?view=word-js-preview#word-word-range-getbookmarks-member(1))

```js
 await Word.run(async (context) => {
    const bookmarks = context.document.getBookmarks(true); // Set includeHidden to true
    context.load(bookmarks, 'items');

    await context.sync();

     // Iterate through the bookmarks and log their names
      for (let i = 0; i < bookmarks.items.length; i++) {
           const bookmark = bookmarks.items[i];
            console.log('Bookmark Name:', bookmark);
           }
      });
```

Comment: You need to say more than "not done". What do you expect to happen and what actually happens? Do you get any error messages? Can you reproduce the problem in the Script Lab tool?

Comment: I need all hidden bookmarks and I got.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using this I got all hidden bookmarks

```
      await Word.run(async (context) => {
      const body = context.document.body.getRange();
      let bookmarks = body.getBookmarks(true, true);

      await context.sync();
      console.log(bookmarks.value);
  });
```